# Disable the close button for window.open inChrome/Mozilla

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mozilla, window.open

```
window.open("my html page link", "_blank", "toolbar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, ,titlebar=no,top=500, left=500, width=400, height=400");
```

Need to disable the red color cross button and maximize button. Not working in Mozilla/Chrome
Tried with "yes|no|1|0" for all the optional parameters, none of the parameters working.

Comment: What you mean by "red cross button"? The button to close the window? You want to open a popup the user can't close? It works in any browser you tested?

Comment: Some browsers limit the number of options they support for security reasons and I think this is one of them.

Comment: You can't do that, but maybe you could use the fullscreen API.

Comment: yes the close window, i want to restrict the user to close it.

Comment: You may want to consider a floating iframe instead of a popup. It's limited because it has to stay on top of your main window, but if that works for you, you'll have a lot more control over what the user can and can't do with it.

Answer (score 0):

For obvious security reasons, you can't hijack the user monitor and place a popup the user can't close.

So the answer is no, you can't avoid that button to be there.

Comment: We are using this popup for P2P video/audio  calls, user will have a option for EndCall in the html page to close the popup window. I just want to know is it possible to disable the close window.

Comment: The answer is no, doesn't matter if you have legitimate reasons and offer another way of closing the window, unfortunately much other people on the net doesn't have the same ethics, so browser can't allow that to anyone.